# Проверка наличия параметра в командной строке // Проверка аргументов командной строки на наличие

Tags: c++

Всем доброго времени суток.

Возникла необходимость сделать небольшую защиту клиента, на проверку наличия параметра в CMD, если он есть то клиент стартует, тобиж client.dll запускается.

Как можно сделать так что бы проверялось несколько параметров, допустим если в CMD имеется один из параметров:
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.2
127.0.0.3
То клиент стартовал.
Сам пробовал что то сделать, но никак не получается

````
    {
        if (dwReasonForCall == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) {
            DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hModule);
            TCHAR* cmdline = GetCommandLine();
            if (StrStr(cmdline, "127.0.0.1"))  {
                LoadLibrary("client.dll");
            }
        }
        return TRUE;
    }```
````

Comment: Что конкретно у вас не получается?

Comment: Хотелось бы, что бы проверялось на наличие одного из указанных параметров, и при наличии любого из указанных, шла загрузка библиотеки, с один параметров "127.0.0.1" загрузка идёт, а вот как добавить  другие параметры я не знаю :(

Comment: Ну сделайте `if (StrStr(cmdline, "127.0.0.1")||StrStr(cmdline, "127.0.0.2")||StrStr(cmdline, "127.0.0.3"))`

Comment: Да, уже сделал, хотел сюда поделиться как, но ты меня опередил)

Answer (score 0):

[Andrey Mihalev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/263405/andrey-mihalev)

```
if (dwReasonForCall == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) {
    DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hModule);
    TCHAR* cmdline = GetCommandLine();
    if (StrStr(cmdline, "127.0.0.1") || StrStr(cmdline, "127.0.0.1") || StrStr(cmdline, "127.0.0.1") || StrStr(cmdline, "127.0.0.1")) {
        LoadLibrary("client.dll");
    }
}
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: В этом коде нет смысла. Чем он отличается от исходного?